# How to modify the data into a table using Userform for VBA Excel (I want to do the range to lastrow instead to do C7:C80000

Tags: excel, vba

I want to change this Code to modify data into a table using userform but I need to make the range to the lastrow instead to do C7:C80000.

This code is filtering the column to find the invoice number and will modify the data. How can I achieve this?

```
  ThisWorkbook.Activate
   Dim X As Long
   Dim xx As Long
   Dim fwr As Integer
   Dim fwo As Integer

   mer = " Data Error : "
   mtk = " Data Duplicate Error : "

    fwr = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Rep.Range("C7:C80000"), Me.CbInvStore.Value, 
    Rep.Range("F7:F80000"), Me.TbInvNo.Value)     'I need to change it to lastrow 
    fwrc = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Repc.Range("B9:B30000"), 
    Me.CbInvStore.Value, Repc.Range("D9:D30000"), Me.TbInvNo.Value)     'I need to change it 
    to lastrow 
    fwo = Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1 ' no of items
     '==========================================================

     If fwr < 1 Then:  MsgBox mer & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please enter the invoice number ", 
     vbCritical + vbMsgBoxLeft, "Inventory Program ": Exit Sub
      If fwrs < 1 Then:  MsgBox mer & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please enter the invoice number ", 
     vbCritical + vbMsgBoxLeft, "Inventory Program ": Exit Sub

     If fwrc < 1 Then:  MsgBox mer & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & " Invoice number not found in the 
      statement of the client's account", vbCritical + vbMsgBoxLeft, "Inventory Program ": 
     Exit Sub
    If fwrc > 1 Then:  MsgBox mtk & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & " Duplicate invoice number " & fwrc & "  
       Once ", vbCritical + vbMsgBoxLeft, "Inventory Program ": Exit Sub
     If fwo < 1 Then:  MsgBox mer & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & " There are no items to be adjusted ", 
       vbCritical + vbMsgBoxLeft, "Inventory Program ": Exit Sub

      confir = MsgBox("Would you like to save the change...  ?", vbOKCancel, "Inventory 
          Program  
            ")
       If confir = vbCancel Then: Exit Sub

       Application.ScreenUpdating = False

      On Error GoTo 1
           
         'this is worksheet Report 
      With Rep
        .Select
       .Unprotect ("0000")
        AutoFilterMode = False
     .Range("$C$6:$Z$6").AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=Me.CbInvStore.Value
      .Range("$C$6:$Z$6").AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:=Me.TbInvNo.Value

      lastrow = .Range("F80000").End(xlUp).Row + 1        'I need to change it to lastrow 
      .Range("$C$6:$Z$6").AutoFilter

     If fwo = fwr Then
      X = lastrow - fwr
       xx = lastrow - 1
     ElseIf fwo > fwr Then
      d = fwo - fwr
      X = lastrow - fwr
       xx = lastrow + d - 1
      .Range(Cells(lastrow, "c"), Cells(xx, "c")).Select
     Selection.EntireRow.Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
             ElseIf fwo < fwr Then
       X = lastrow - fwr
      xx = X + fwo - 1
      Y = xx + 1
       z = lastrow - 1
       .Range(Cells(Y, "c"), Cells(z, "c")).Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Delete
        Else
         MsgBox "There is somthing wrong. will be exit ", vbCritical, "Inventory Program  "
      End If

       Me.TbDate.Text = Format(Me.TbDate.Text, "dd/mm/yyyy")

      .Range(Rep.Cells(X, "B"), Rep.Cells(xx, "B")) = Me.comDepartment.Value   
      .Range(Rep.Cells(X, "C"), Rep.Cells(xx, "C")) = Me.CbInvStore.Value   
      .Range(Rep.Cells(X, "D"), Rep.Cells(xx, "D")) = Me.CbPayment.Value 
      .Range(Rep.Cells(X, "E"), Rep.Cells(xx, "E")) = Me.Lbl_typ.Caption   
      .Range(Rep.Cells(X, "F"), Rep.Cells(xx, "F")) = Format(Me.TbInvNo.Value, "00000")  
               
       .Range(Rep.Cells(X, "G"), Rep.Cells(xx, "G")) = Me.TbDate.Value    'date
       .Range(Rep.Cells(X, "H"), Rep.Cells(xx, "H")) = Me.CbCustomerName.Value  
        .Cells(X, "I") = Me.TbTotalNetPrice.Value   'balance
        .Range(Rep.Cells(X, "T"), Rep.Cells(xx, "T")) = Users.Range("aw6").Value   
   
          Inv.Unprotect ("0000")
       
          .Protect Password:=("0000")
          End With
  '=========================================================================================
       'This worksheet Report Customer 
        With Repc
       .Select
        .Unprotect ("8521")
          AutoFilterMode = False
       .Range("$B$8:$P$8").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Me.CbInvStore.Value
        .Range("$B$8:$P$8").AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=Me.TbInvNo.Value

         ss = .Range("f30000").End(xlUp).Row       'I need to change it to lastrow 
        .Range("$d$8:$r$8").AutoFilter

        .Cells(ss, "F").Value = Me.CbCustomerName.Value  'customer
         .Cells(ss, "B").Value = Me.CbInvStore.Value  'inv store
         .Cells(ss, "C").Value = Me.TbDate.Value  'date
          .Cells(ss, "K").Value = Me.CbPayment.Value

          .Cells(ss, "O").Value = Me.CbMrName.Value  'mr
          .Cells(ss, "P").Value = Users.Range("aw6").Value  'user

           'CASE RETURN=====================
           If Me.CbInvStore.Value = Data.Range("BF9") Or Me.CbInvStore.Value = 
          Data.Range("BF10") Then
          .Cells(ss, "I") = Me.TbTotalNetPrice.Value    
        Else
           .Cells(ss, "G") = Me.TbTotalNetPrice.Value   
          End If

       If Me.CbPayment.Value = "Cash" Then
       .Cells(ss, "H") = Me.TbTotalNetPrice.Value  
         Else
          End If
           .Protect Password:=("0000")
            End With
          
          confir = MsgBox(" Change successfully Saved", vbInformation, "Inventory Program")
          
            1 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

[Sheet Repc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRMlU.png) table resize 80000
[Sheet Rep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKXGE.png)  table resize 80000

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CTRL + SHIFT + Up method:

```
Rep.Range("C7:C" & Rep.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(Xlup).Row)
```

The code sets the position to the last row (`Rows.Count`) and makes a skip up to the next filled row (`End(xlUp)`) and returns the row number, which then is concatenated with this `Rep.Range("C7:C" &`

Comment: Where I can add this code?

Comment: This line for example: `fwr = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Rep.Range("C7:C80000"), Me.CbInvStore.Value, Rep.Range("F7:F80000"), Me.TbInvNo.Value)` could be changed to: `fwr = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Rep.Range("C7:C" & Rep.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(Xlup).Row), Me.CbInvStore.Value, Rep.Range("F7:F" & Rep.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(Xlup).Row), Me.TbInvNo.Value)`

Comment: How about this code      lastrow = .Range("F80000").End(xlUp).Row + 1

Comment: This will not work if there are more than 80000 lines of data, and it will set the pointer on the first empty cell below the data.

Comment: I tried the code that you gave me but it's modified the data only the sheet Rep and  another sheet is nothing did

Comment: Then you need to change the other places where you use arbitrary values for row numbers. I posted how you need to change one place of the code, you need to change the rest the same way

Comment: I did already, I changed all same like your code but when the cod is run only modified sheet Rep

Comment: `fwr = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Rep.Range("C7:C" & Rep.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row), Me.CbInvStore.Value, Rep.Range("F7:F" & Rep.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row), Me.TbInvNo.Value)
fwrs = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Sales.Range("C7:C" & Sales.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row), Me.CbInvStore.Value)
fwrc = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Repc.Range("B9:B" & Repc.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row), Me.CbInvStore.Value, Repc.Range("D9:D" & Repc.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row), Me.TbInvNo.Value)`